# Practical way to temporarily shut down a database

Tags: sql-server

What would be the most practical way to shut down a database to access for any user?

I need to practically shut down a specific database on a SQL Server for test purposes, and would like to know the most practical common solution.

Thanx

Comment: Set a Database to Single-user Mode http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can take if offline or open as a single user.

To take it offline adapt the followin script, [original at sqlauthority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/04/24/sql-server-t-sql-script-to-take-database-offline-take-database-online/)

```
-- Create Test DB
CREATE DATABASE [myDB]
GO
-- Take the Database Offline
ALTER DATABASE [myDB] SET OFFLINE WITH
ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
-- Take the Database Online
ALTER DATABASE [myDB] SET ONLINE
GO
-- Clean up
DROP DATABASE [myDB]
GO
```

To make it available to a single user account [original at sqlauthority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/11/sql-server-alter-database-dbname-set-single_user-with-rollback-immediate/):

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDbName]
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will limit access to only current connection:

```
alter database [yourdbname] set single_user with rollback immediate
```

Rollback:

```
alter database [yourdbname] set multi_user
```